# Setting Servlet Context Initialization Parameters for Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlets, grails

I have a Grails application that has a simple Websocket endpoint, shown here:

```
@WebListener
@ServerEndpoint("/chatEndpoint/{chatId}")
public class WebsocketChatroomEndpoint implements ServletContextListener {

  static ConfigObject config

  @Override
  public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    ServletContext servletContext = sce.servletContext
    ServerContainer serverContainer = servletContext.getAttribute("javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer")
    try {
      ApplicationContext ctx = (ApplicationContext) servletContext.getAttribute(GA.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)
      config = ctx.grailsApplication.config
      serverContainer.defaultMaxSessionIdleTimeout = 0
    } catch (IOException e) {
      log.error(e.message, e)
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
  }

  @OnOpen
  public void onOpen(Session userSession, @PathParam("chatId") String chatId) {
    // Do some stuff
  }

  @OnMessage
  public String onMessage(String message, Session userSession) throws IOException {
    // Handle message received
  }

  @OnClose
  public void onClose(Session userSession, CloseReason reason) {
    // Handle close
  }

  @OnError
  public void onError(Throwable t) {
    // Handle error
  }
}
```

The endpoint works fine, but the problem I am running into is that when deploying to Tomcat 8, idle connections are disconnected after 60 seconds.

The [Tomcat Websocket How-To](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html) states that this value can be changed by setting the following servlet context initialization parameter: `org.apache.tomcat.websocket.executorKeepAliveTimeSeconds`.

I've set this parameter in the `web.xml` file like so:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.tomcat.websocket.executorKeepAliveTimeSeconds</param-name>
    <param-value>1000</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And, when I access the parameter in the `contextInitialized` method of my Listener, the value is set properly.

```
@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
  ServletContext servletContext = sce.servletContext

  // Logs "1000"
  log.debug(servletContext.getInitParameter("org.apache.tomcat.websocket.executorKeepAliveTimeSeconds"))
}
```

The problem is that the endpoint still times out after 60 seconds, no matter what I set this value to. I've tried setting the value inside of Tomcat's `context.xml` file, as well as programmatically setting it in my listener. Does anyone have any idea how to override Tomcat's default value of 60 seconds for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've resolved the issue, and I was obviously out of my mind when troubleshooting this.

I have nginx reverse-proxying connections to Tomcat. Tomcat was setting the value properly, but the `proxy_read_timeout` in nginx defaults to 60 seconds. Increasing this value in my nginx site config fixed the problem.